# Building Libraries in C#

Tags: c#, xna

This is likely an incredibly simple error on my part but whenever I try to use a custom XNA Game Library or custom C# Library that I have made which contains multiple class files when compiled with the inbuilt compiler in Visual C# 2010, I cannot access any class aside from the first class created within the library, even when using the `using` keyword to define the namespace. For example, if I had a library which I created calling the first class `Foo`, if I then add another class `MyFoo` I will only have access to the `Foo` class when I import the library into my main file. Any attempt to reference `MyFoo` will fail, and the IDE does not recognise it as a class. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure your class is public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure any classes in your library that you want to access are marked public. By default in Visual Studio, a class may lack the public access modifier

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {
```

So add the word "public" to the class like:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
```

You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Solved my problem completely, much obliged